# How to wait for Async/Await with nested foreach loop to be completed

Tags: node.js, async-await

how can I wait for getVideoCountForAuthor() to be completed with all async queries?

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("START");

    (async () => {
        let uniqueAuthors = await getInfluencersForHashTags("winter", {  sessionList: [TTSessions]});
        uniqueAuthors = await getVideoCountForAuthor(uniqueAuthors);
    })()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("EVERYTHING DONE");
        })  ;


});

async function getVideoCountForAuthor(authors) {

    return _.each(authors, async function (author, i, authors) {

        let feed = await TikTokScraper.user(author.username, {number: 10, sessionList: [TTSessions]});

        let authorMeta = author.authorMeta;

        let videocounts = _.map(feed.collector, function (post) {
            return post.playCount;
        });

        console.log("set videocount");

    });
}
```

**LOG:**

```
START
EVERYTHING DONE
set videocount
set videocount
set videocount
set videocount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `lodash` you can use `map` instead of `each` because map will return an array of answers (In your case empty Promises) so to change that scenario to the same scenario of each you can do this:

```
async function getVideoCountForAuthor(authors) {

    return _.map(authors, async function (author, i, authors) {

        let feed = await TikTokScraper.user(author.username, {number: 10, sessionList: [TTSessions]});

        let authorMeta = author.authorMeta;

        let videocounts = _.map(feed.collector, function (post) {
            return post.playCount;
        });

        console.log("set videocount");
        return author;
    });
}
```

Now, the answer will be an array of promises, so you can make a [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in `getVideoCountForAuthor` or in the parent function.

The first case will be:

```
async function getVideoCountForAuthor(authors) {

    return await Promise.all(_.map(authors, async function (author, i, authors) {

        let feed = await TikTokScraper.user(author.username, {number: 10, sessionList: [TTSessions]});

        let authorMeta = author.authorMeta;

        let videocounts = _.map(feed.collector, function (post) {
            return post.playCount;
        });

        console.log("set videocount");
        return author;
    }));
}
```

Your output will be:

```
START
set videocount
set videocount
set videocount
set videocount
EVERYTHING DONE
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a "modern" alternative for lodash to get all these helper function in nodejs?

Comment: I don't use `lodash` so I can't tell you for sure. But in itself, this is a typical case in javascript. Having a "forEach" with promises is very complicated. I recommended to use a loop, a map or store them in an array, so later you can use the `Promise.all` and use the `await`. Which of the 3 should I use? It depends on your solution and the problem you have

Answer (score 1):

Ohh wow. It works with a **for loop**. Is that the best option?

```
async function getVideoCountForAuthor(authors) {

    for (const author of authors) {

        let feed = await TikTokScraper.user(author.username, {number: 10, sessionList: [TTSessions]});

        let authorMeta = author.authorMeta;

        let videocounts = _.map(feed.collector, function (post) {
            return post.playCount;
        });

        //let newAuthor = author;
        // uniqueAuthors[i].medianVideoCounts = median(videocounts);
        console.log("set videocount");

    };
}
```

Comment: Depends, I prefer an array of promises and await this with `await Promise.All(arrayOfPromises)`. In the `for of` the next author will be executed when the previous author complete. In an array of promises, the authors will be executed asynchronously. So, is depends to you and the solution o:

Comment: NOTE: In your original code you are returning an array of `authors`. In this code, you are returning `undefined`